# Trigger click on link on jquery mobile not working

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, click

I tried triggering a link via .trigger() function but is not working

```
<a data-role="button" id="redirectprofile_btn" href="profile.html" rel="external" style="display:block;">Profile</a>
```

Once i click the link manually, it will display the profile page (profile.html, with its own css and js) but if i use

```
 $("#redirectprofile_btn").click() or $("#redirectprofile_btn").trigger('click'),
```

it wont redirect.

Im new to jquerymobile, any help would really be great.

Thanks

Comment: why to trigger a click? use `changePage` function.  for jQM 1.3 `$.mobile.changePage("profile.html")`. for jQM 1.4 `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "profile.html");`

Comment: profile.html has a css file which conflicts to the first pagge (index.html) if i use pagecontainer.change

Comment: then what you need is `window.location.href = "profile.html";`.

Answer (score 0):

Use event.prevent default() followed by event.stopImmediatePropogation then changePage to the links href attr value.